# How to animate a non-layer property?

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

Is there a way to animate properties of my own classes, using the property animation facilities provided by Core Animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless these properties wrap calls to animatable properties themselves; for example, a "appearance" property whose setter modifies the "transform" and "alpha" properties, can be animated in an animation context.

Check out for "animatable properties" in the SDK documentation to know which properties can be animated; you can't add more to this list.